# Right Single Quote vs Acute

Tags: html

I've always thought that `&rsquo;` looks better and more distinctive than `&acute;` when typing apostrophes in HTML. I was wondering, other than visual difference, is there any grammatical or syntax reason for not using `&rsquo;` in place of an `&acute;` to produce apostrophes?

Comment: Note that you can use the right single quote as such (’), making HTML source more readable. And in the very rare cases where you might need the acute, it can also be written as such (´).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&acute;` is an accent, not an apostrophe. So yes, there are grammatical reasons to not use `&acute;` when what you really want is an apostrophe.

Comment: OK, but then `&rsquo;` is actually a single quotation, not an apostrophe.

Comment: That's true. You can get a straight apostrophe with `&#39;`

Comment: @Styphon it started out as a quote, but it's accepted to use as an apostrophe now, even in the highest Unicode circles. Originally, U+02BC was an apostrophe, at least as a letter replacement in words like "canʼt", but it has all but been deprecated now.

Comment: OK, so just a complete misunderstanding of what the characters are from my point of view then :). Thanks for the clarification.